# mktime() into mysql datetime column?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mktime

I don't know if it's possible, but I'm trying to assign different dates to each user as the are entered into the database using a loop (I know that bit's possible). To do this I'm building the timestamp using mktime() but my column is datetime (for the purpose of MySQL ORDERBY timestamp DESC) and, naturally, the two don't go together.

My code:

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $user_uid => $num) {
      $i = 1;
        while($num > 0) {
          $i++;
          $t = new DateTime("Y-m-d H:i:s", date(mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012)));
          $num--;
        }
     }
?>
```

At the moment this returns: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
An amount has changed, my code now reads like this:

```
foreach($arr as $user_uid => $num) {
    $i = 1;
        while($num > 0) {
            $i++;
            $t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012));
            $num--;
        }

$game = "INSERT INTO wd_game_$gid (game_uid,user_uid,lastmove,startcountry,money) VALUES ('$gid','$user_uid',FROM_UNIXTIME('$t'),'$rand_c','$money')";
```

This now inserts: 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1 - use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` on databse layer

You can do this on the database side, using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function (the argument is Unix epoch timestamp, so this is the same as the result of your `mktime()`).

### Solution 2 - fix your current code

Also your code is incorrect, because you pass incorrect date into `DateTime` constructor (see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)). You pass `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012))`. You can even resign from using `DateTime` and just stick to using `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012))`, as this is sufficient for your database insert.

Comment: This inserts  1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @AviateX14: Which insert this? The reason is that you are passing `0` into `FROM_UNIXTIME()` or into `date()`'s second parameter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following... If the $t variable value was, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(1, 2, 3, $i, 1, 2012)) - it should input the date/time right? Not, 1970-01-01 00:00:00, which it does.

Comment: @AviateX14: This is why I named part of my answer "_Solution 1..._", and the second part "_Solution 2..._". You mixed them both :) Just pick one and 1) assign result of `mktime()` to the `$t` variable, then do `FROM_UNIXTIME($t)` in the query, or 2) assign the result of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012))` to the `$t` variable and then just do `$t` in the query (see, in this case there is no `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

You're approach isn't quite right I don't think. Try:

```
foreach($arr as $user_uid => $num) {
  $i = 1;
    while($num > 0) {
      $i++;
      $t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012));
      $num--;
    }
 }
```

The DateTime() constructor has two optional parameters. A string representing the time and a string representing the time zone - see [the DateTime __construct reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: That also inserted: 0000-00-00 00:00:00, As the other commenter said, my problem may be elsewhere, thanks I'll check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$t = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012)));
```

(The format string is the first parameter of `date`)

---

**EDIT**: As I've said in the comments, don't confuse [php DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) with [MySQL DATETIME data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

You can do this:

```
$t = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012);  // $t contains now a unix timestamp

// ... 

$game = "INSERT INTO wd_game_$gid (game_uid,user_uid,lastmove,startcountry,money) VALUES ".
        "('$gid','$user_uid',FROM_UNIXTIME($t),'$rand_c','$money')";
```

Or this:

```
$t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012));
// $t contains a textual representation of MySQL DATETIME value

// ... 

$game = "INSERT INTO wd_game_$gid (game_uid,user_uid,lastmove,startcountry,money) VALUES ".
        "('$gid','$user_uid','$t','$rand_c','$money')";
```

Comment: Still only inserts "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: @AviateX14, where? If i run `print_r(new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2012))));` I get the correct output. So your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I'll put the full code in the question as an edit, one moment.

Comment: @AviateX14, should `$t` hold a timestamp or an instance of `DateTime` class? Don't confuse php `DateTime` class with MySQL `DATETIME` data type.

Comment: I did get them confused, thanks for clearing that up, using the FROM_UNIXTIME(), it inserts 1970-01-01 00:00:00, progress at least..

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong ;)  `mktime` produces a timestamp and `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)` creates a SQL DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have to pass to `FROM_UNIXTIME` function the string representation of the date since you are already using `DATETIME` datatype. `FROM_UNIXTIME` parameter is unsigned int, thus the evaluation results 1970 as the year which is the equivalent of the start of the epoch

```
foreach($arr as $user_uid => $num) {
$i = 1;
    while($num > 0) {
        $i++;
        $t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012));
        $num--;
    }

$game = "INSERT INTO wd_game_$gid (game_uid,user_uid,lastmove,startcountry,money) VALUES      ('$gid','$user_uid','$t','$rand_c','$money')";
```